# Is there a way to specify a proxy user id in a VBA Macro to connect to oracle?

Tags: vba, oracle, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently trying to connect to an Oracle database from VBA.  Below is the code I am running in VBA to try to establish the initial connection. Unfortunately, this code produces an “ORA-01017” error mentioning that my username/password is invalid. I have SQL Developer installed and when I try to login with the same credentials/info, I successfully connect. I also tried instead setting UID = userid in the VBA code below and the connection didn’t throw an error, but I can’t query any tables. The same thing happens if I try the same in SQL developer.

After doing some reading, it looks like the info in the brackets is my proxy user id and I need to somehow specify that separately from my UID, but I can’t figure out how I would go about that. Has anyone else had any experience with this or have any guidance? Let me know if there is any additional details I can provide.

```
Sub Ora_Connection()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.recordset

StrCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; Uid=userid[database name];Pwd=UserPWD;" & _
"CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
"(HOST=HostName)(PORT=1521))" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXXX)));"
con.Open (StrCon)
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195399/oracle-connecting-as-a-proxy-user-via-connection-string

Comment: @TimWilliams in the provided document ```OracleConnection``` object is used to proxy nothing about ```ADODB.Connection```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like its possible to connect to proxy user with ADODB .

One another alternative is to use `alter session set current_schema = Proxy_user` run this after you open the session.

The only trouble with this is that the grants should be there for the actual user, here proxy user just allows us to avoid using identifiers.